# mongodb use 'copyDatabase', but don't copy collections

Tags: mongodb

I use 'copyDatabase' to copy local db to remote db.

cosole just return

`{
    "ok" : 1.0
}`

db was created but dont' have any collecitons in it.

collections was not copied.

I try same command on local, copy db just on local.
It works.

Remote is Ubuntu on aws
Remote mongo version is 2.4.9

Comment: What version of MongoDB is the remote instance running? Are you connecting to it with a MongoDB 2.4 shell, or using the same version of the shell as the remote instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on Mongo 3.4 but you can try:

`db.cloneCollection(from, collection, query)`

or:

`db.cloneDatabase("hostname")`

[Docs are here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/method/db.cloneDatabase/)

EDIT:

Based upon the OP's comment
use MongoDump and MongoRestore in v2.4
This will dump the db and collections and then restore where you want
[Docs are here for that in 2.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/tutorial/backup-with-mongodump/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.   Your command is to copy a remote database to the current database.  But I want to copy locol to remote.

Comment: @TomatoPeter Edited my answer

Comment: mongodump and mongorestore works.  And I found a script to hanle it. [mongo-sync](https://github.com/sheharyarn/mongo-sync)

Comment: @TomatoPeter you can also download [RoboMongo](https://robomongo.org/) or [MongoBooster](https://mongobooster.com/) which will handle them and all shell commands